# Best way to delay REST call until after user enters login info to modal view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, modalviewcontroller

My app has a login screen before a user goes into the main view. I will do a `presentModalViewController:` if a user hasn't logged in. In my main view's `viewDidLoad:` I have a call to a REST API which requires the username and password of the user. Now, if the user has logged in then this is fine.

The problem is that even when the login view is shown, this main view behind the login view is still making a call to the REST API, although it's not supposed to until the modal view is dismissed. So what is the best way to resolve this? Putting the API call into `viewWillAppear:`? A delegate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` will however get called after `viewDidLoad`.

You can use delegates. The login controller can give a call back to its delegate something like `-(void) loginController:(LoginViewController *) controller didLogin`

And here you can make your call to REST API.

Comment: are you sure that's the right way to declare a delegate? don't you need a variable after didLogin?

Answer (score 1):

Go the delegate route.  Implementing the code in viewWillAppear: will cause it to be executed multiple times, whereas if you use a delegate your code will be called just once.